# Sink gargle after draining or when flushing toilet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, p-trap

I have recently installed a new vanity but had to extend the trap back to the drain as it didn’t line up like it did before replacing the vanity. Before it never made noise when draining or flushing the toilet. It seems to drain fine but the gargle noises are concerning. Is this a venting issue or issue with how I have the trap set up? Would adding an AAV help? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Yes, you need proper venting. This drain isn't legal by modern standards. Any good answers depend on context. Please revise to provide more detail about your entire plumbing circuit.

Comment: FYI, nylon slip-joint parts are normally only used for the trap (so it can be removed for cleaning, etc.). The rest of your pipes should be cement-welded PVC or ABS.

Comment: The red rubber gasket visible inside the plastic nut may be on backwards (hard to tell from photo).